# Sim800L HTTP post request stop working after a while

Tags: arduino-mega, power, gsm, debugging

I am desperate to get my SIM800L module (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SIM800L-GPRS-GSM-Module-Board-Quadband-QUAD-BAND-Antenna-for-MCU-Arduino-/321992759287) sending POST requests for a long period of time... Sometimes it stops after 100 requests in a row, sometimes 300 so it's really weird.

Everytime I run it, it sends the request for a while (between 1 and 3 hours) and suddenly stops on these AT commands:

```
---> AT+HTTPINIT
<---

OK
```

When it works the OK is on the same line and it goes on to the next AT command.

```
        ---> AT+HTTPTERM
    <--- ERROR
         ---> AT+HTTPINIT
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPPARA="CID"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPPARA="UA"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPPARA="URL"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPDATA=1221,10000
    <--- DOWNLOAD
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPACTION=1
    <--- OK
Status: 201
Len: 0
    ---> AT+HTTPREAD
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+HTTPTERM
    <--- OK
```

I thought it was a powering problem so I connected the module to the VIN pin of my arduino mega via a buck converter but the problem is still here!

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong? I can send you the code if needed.

Many thanks in advance
Pauline

Comment: Cross-posting? At least include your code instead of this indecipherable nonsense.

Comment: Could you try enabling "verbose error codes" (or atleast numeric error codes) using `AT+CMEE=2` or `AT+CMEE=1` and then post the (error) response on `AT+HTTPINIT`. There are no errors in the log you have attached.

Comment: Maybe it just lost signal. You might want to make your code check for errors. And if it finds a response with: "Error" it will attempt to re-send. (Maybe add a timeout or re-try limit also).